# how to set underline style on subtitle highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

is that any method to show underline in highchart subtitle, i try insert this text "mc quiz **memantau** *dudi yuhu* koka kolaa h<sub>2</sub>o bang<sup>et</sup> yeah okeksdslklsd skjlk" but only show just bold and italic

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Annotations'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'mc quiz <strong>memantau </strong><em>dudi yuhu </em><u>koka kolaa</u> h<sub>2</sub>o bang<sup>et</sup>&nbsp;yeah okeksdslklsd skjlk'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['y', 'id'],
        data: [[39.9, '0'], [71.5, '1'], [106.4, '2'], [129.2, '3'], [144.0, '4'], [176.0, '5']]
    }],

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
            point: '0',
            format: '{y:.2f} mm'
        }, {
            point: '1',
            text: '{point.plotY:.2f} px'
        }, {
            point: '2'
        }, {
            point: '3'
        }, {
            point: '4'
        }, {
            point: '5'
        }],
        labelOptions: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (this.series.dataMax - this.y).toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

is there posible to make text like that ? , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the text is converted to `<text>` and `<tspan>` SVG elements, to use different tags such as `<u>` enable the `useHTML` option:

```
    subtitle: {
        useHTML: true,
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncf3rhk5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle.useHTML

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">` too

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Annotations'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">mc quiz yeah okeksdslklsd skjlk</span>'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['y', 'id'],
        data: [[39.9, '0'], [71.5, '1'], [106.4, '2'], [129.2, '3'], [144.0, '4'], [176.0, '5']]
    }],

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    annotations: [{
        labels: [{
            point: '0',
            format: '{y:.2f} mm'
        }, {
            point: '1',
            text: '{point.plotY:.2f} px'
        }, {
            point: '2'
        }, {
            point: '3'
        }, {
            point: '4'
        }, {
            point: '5'
        }],
        labelOptions: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (this.series.dataMax - this.y).toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```